# lateinit property valorFinal has not been initialized

Tags: kotlin

estoy empezando a programar en Kotlin y me he encontrado con un error en mi código el cual no lo puedo solucionar. Sinceramente no sé qué puedo hacer, por eso a continuación os mostraré el código y el error. De esta manera, si alguien sabe cómo arreglarlo agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Código:

```
    package com.example.conversordunitats

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import android.text.Editable as TextEditable

lateinit var valorInicial: EditText
var unitatInicial = ""
var unitatFinal = ""
var valorPrevFinal = 0
lateinit var valorFinal: EditText


class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity(){
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.listaUnidades)
        val spinnerDivisor = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.listaUnidadesDivisor)
        val listaContenido = resources.getStringArray(R.array.opcionesMasa)

        val adaptador = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listaContenido)
        spinner.adapter = adaptador
        spinnerDivisor.adapter = adaptador

        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object :
                AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, listaContenido[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                unitatInicial = listaContenido[position]
                valorInicial = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.valorEntrada)
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
            }
        spinnerDivisor.onItemSelectedListener = object:
                AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, listaContenido[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                unitatFinal = listaContenido[position]
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.botonCalcular).setOnClickListener {
            conversionUnidadesMasa()
            addResult(it)
        }
    }

    private fun conversionUnidadesMasa(){
        val value: String = valorInicial.text.toString()
        val IntInicial = value.toInt()

        if (unitatInicial == "kg") {
        when (unitatFinal) {
            "kg" -> valorPrevFinal = IntInicial
            "hg" -> valorPrevFinal = IntInicial*10
            "dag" -> valorPrevFinal = IntInicial*100
            "g" -> valorPrevFinal = IntInicial*1000
            "dg" -> valorPrevFinal = IntInicial*10000
            "cg" -> valorPrevFinal = IntInicial*100000
            "mg" -> valorPrevFinal = IntInicial*1000000
        }
    }
        var resultadoString = valorPrevFinal.toString()
        valorFinal.text = TextEditable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(resultadoString)
    }
    private fun addResult (view: View) {
        var resultadoTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultado) as TextView
        resultadoTextView.text = valorFinal.text
        resultadoTextView.visibility=View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.conversordunitats, PID: 11366
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property valorFinal has not been initialized
        at com.example.conversordunitats.MainActivityKt.getValorFinal(MainActivity.kt:13)
        at com.example.conversordunitats.MainActivity.conversionUnidadesMasa(MainActivity.kt:75)
        at com.example.conversordunitats.MainActivity.access$conversionUnidadesMasa(MainActivity.kt:16)
        at com.example.conversordunitats.MainActivity$onCreate$3.onClick(MainActivity.kt:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Hola, creo que te falta iniciar el EditText, sería algo así: "valorFinal = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.valorSalida)"

Comment: He probado lo que dices, pero yo no tengo definido R.id.valorSalida y entonces me sale el siguiente error: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Comment: Ya, si el nombre del EditText era orientativo, para dejar claro el ejemplo, pero en algún elemento tendrás que "pintar" el resultado y asignarle el valor que quieres, no?

Comment: He añadido valorFinal = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.resultado) justo debajo de setContentView(R.layout.activity_main). Pero ahora cuando ejecuto la aplicación no se enciende. Además, ya estoy "pintando" el resultado dentro de la función addResult por medio de var resultadoTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultado) as TextView. ¿Alguna otra sugerencia?

Comment: Los elementos de la vista los deberías inicializar todos en el mismo sitio, en el onCreate, antes de realizar las operaciones. El resultado no lo había visto, lo tienes en otro método, si lo generalizas como variable global debería bastar y no tendrías que inicializar valorFinal como te he dicho esta mañana, es más, valorFinal debería ser un String, y no un editText, sobre todo si no lo tienes definido en el xml.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya me funciona. Lo agradezco de verdad porque ayer me pasé varias horas tratando de resolver el problema :)

Comment: Nada, para eso estamos.

Answer (score 0):

Los elementos de la vista los deberías inicializar todos en el mismo sitio, en el "onCreate()", antes de realizar las operaciones.

Si generalizas como variable global el "TextView" R.id.resultado debería bastar y no tendrías que inicializar valorFinal, es más, valorFinal debería ser un String, y no un editText, sobre todo si no lo tienes definido en el la vista "XML".

Answer (score 0):

Lo que indica el mensaje de error :

> lateinit property valorFinal has not been initialized

es simplemente que la variable no se ha inicializado y la tratas de acceder.

> Acceder a una propiedad `lateinit` antes de que se haya inicializado
> genera una excepción especial que identifica claramente la propiedad a
> la que se accede y el hecho de que no se ha inicializado.

Para verificar si una `lateinit var` ya se ha inicializado, puedes usar `.isInitialized` en la referencia a esa propiedad:

```
if (::myVariable.isInitialized) {
    println(myVariable)
}
```

o también:

```
if (myVariable != null) {
    println(myVariable)
}
```

En este caso el problema es que estas inicializando la vista fuera de `onCreate()`, al inicializarla ya podrás usarla en cualquier otro método de tu clase.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


       //Inicializa EditText.
       valorFinal = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.resultado) 
       ...
       ...
 }
```